# Django .update() on queryset containing a duplicated objects

Tags: python, django

I need to increment a `tickets` field in multiple User objects at once. The thing is, the queryset can contain the same user multiple times. When that's the case, I want that user's `tickets` field to be incremented as many times as the user can be found in the queryset.

If I use an F() expression, the `.update()` method only increment the field ONCE, regardless of the number of occurences of the user in the queryset.

Here is a code sample:

```
>>> user_list = User.objects.filter(reservations__is_active=True)
>>> user_list
<QuerySet [<User: USER_1>, <User: USER_1>]>  # duplicated object in qs
>>> user_list.values_list('tickets')
<QuerySet [(1,), (1,)]>
>>> user_list.update(tickets=F('tickets')+1)
1
>>> user_list.values_list('tickets')
<QuerySet [(2,), (2,)]>  # I should read 3 tickets instead
```

Can F() expressions be used in this context? If not, how could I achieve this simply?

**Additionnal details:**

As requested in the comments, here are the simplified models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    tickets = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=_("Tickets"),
    )


class Reservation(SafeDeleteModel):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name=_("User"),
        related_name='reservations',
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name=_("Active")
    )
```

Comment: this is a little bit confusing. Do you want: `total_user + 1` or `total_ticket_values_from_all_user + 1` ?

Comment: Please post your models as well and give an example too.

Comment: @waLLe Neither. I have a list of user, each user should see its tickets count incremented by 1. If the same user is found multiple times in the list, his tickets count should be incremented multiple times too.